How to Modify Mesh to Achieve a Circular Shape
I am a beginner in Blender trying to model a g shock watch (reference gwf-1000)
I have modeled the basic shape of the dial but I am struggling to recreate the circular curve that cuts it without messing up the topology of my mesh completely.
Does anyone have any tips on how I could do it?




Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Thanks for the feedback. I will edit the title.

It looks like you don’t actually need the outer circle to cut into anything: I’d just make it a separate mesh rather than trying to make this manifold. Making a boolean cut for the inner circle hole should be easy, just make it slightly bigger than it needs to be so the visible part of the ring inside can go through it. Again, the ring as a whole is its own mesh.

Thanks for the answer. So, just to make sure I understand this correctly, I should use a boolean to make the outer circular shape and make the inside ring a seperate mesh, correct? Won't using a boolean modifier ruin the topology?
